# How to check for more then one cancan attribute at once. Rails syntax knowledge missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I got an if statement like this

```
if can?(:read, Category) || can?(:read, Category2)
```

If a user can read Category or Category2 an link gets shown.

But what if i have like 10 Categorys? There must be a shorter way instead of listing them. I need a bit help.

Comment: can you give us an example why you have this kind of if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some list of objects:

```
categories = [Category1, Category2, Category3]
```

You can get the result using [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), like this:

```
categories.inject(false) { |p, cat| p || can?(:read, cat) }
```

What this literally evaluates to is:

```
(((false || can(:read, Category1)) || can(:read, Category2)) || can(:read, Category3))
```

which of course is equivalent to:

```
can?(:read, Category1) || can?(:read, Category2) || can?(:read, Category3)
```

Comment: that should be `categories.inject(false) { |p, cat| p || can?(:read, cat) }`. if you set it to true the first time, it will always be true

Comment: Yes sorry just realized that!

Comment: i used the answer from jvnill. But i upvote because here i got a better lerning effect :D

Answer (score 2):

i think a faster way to do this (if you already have a list of categories) is to use `detect` since it is an OR and only needs one of the conditions to be true

`categories.detect { |cat| can? :read, cat }`

Answer (score 1):

jvnill's way is okay, but I think this should be faster and clearer since it only returns a boolean:

```
[Category, Category2, ...].any?{|cat| can?(:read, cat)}
```